# Exception Handling - try blocks

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I just started reading about error handling. I understand the basics and how the exceptions are thrown and caught. But I'm lost where I'm supposed to have the try blocks. If I have a program and I want to catch multiple errors that are located in various places, would I enclose my entire code in one try block. From what I've read you can have one try block? Or is error handling use for unit testing? For example, when you run into an error, you would manually enclose that part of the code in the try block to fix it.

Comment: A [good read](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#too-many-trycatch-blocks) on the subject.

Comment: Put one around anywhere exceptions belonging to the same problem may be thrown.

Comment: Only catch exceptions when you can take some sensible recovery action (not just debug output or telling the user there has been an error).  Now you know where to catch exceptions you can place the try-catch blocks.